# Python: how to access an attribute from a __getattribute__ method

Tags: python, infinite-loop, getattribute

I have the following class:

```
class StrLogger(str):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._log_ = []
        str.__init__(self, *args)
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        self._log_.append((self.__name__, attr))
        return str.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

I can initialize a `StrLogger` with `slog = StrLogger('foo')` and I can access all of its inherited methods from `str` and it runs with no problem. The problem is, when I try to retreive the log with either `slog._log_` or `slog.__dict__['_log_']`, the `__getattribute__` method gets stuck in an infinite recursion. I understand why this is happening but my question is, how can I access the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__getattribute__` should exclude `__dict__` and maybe as well `_log_` from logging. Alternatively, you could do something like

```
slog = StrLogger('foo')
thelog = slog._log_
do_stuff_with(slog)
print thelog
```

(untested!)

Comment: Thank you! I see now the recursion was caused by accessing `_log_` during the logging. It still puzzles me that the logging itself worked when other attributes were accessed.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of one way.  Use `object.__getattribute__` (or whatever your superclass is) whenever you need to bypass your customized attribute access.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._log = []
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        _log = object.__getattribute__(self, '_log')
        _log.append(attr)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)

>>> a = C()
>>> a.x = 1
>>> a.x
1
>>> a._log
['x', '_log']
```

Answer (score 2):

The following slightly modified class works:

```
class StrLogger(str):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._log_ = []
        str.__init__(self, *args)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        log = str.__getattribute__(self, '_log_')
        cls = str.__getattribute__(self, '__class__')
        name = cls.__name__
        log.append((name, attr))
        return str.__getattribute__(self, attr)

s = StrLogger('abc')
print(s.title())
print(s.lower())
print(s.upper())
print(s.__dict__)
```

Running it results in

```
Abc
abc
ABC
{'_log_': [('StrLogger', 'title'), ('StrLogger', 'lower'), ('StrLogger', 'upper'), ('StrLogger', '__dict__')]}
```